# How to use union types in the HTML template side of an Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

In the HTML part of an Angular component, I want to display a checkbox or an icon on different conditions. With a permissive model `{ checked?: boolean; icon?: string }`, I can do it like that:

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" *ngIf="!item.icon">
<i class="{{item.icon}}" *ngIf="item.icon">
```

This model enables invalid states like having both `checked` and `icon`. Having a stronger model could rely on an union type: `{ checked: boolean } | { icon: string }`. But it does not work anymore in the HTML, because `checked` nor `icon` are available at the "union type" level but only on the left or right case.

Is there a way to use this model in some tweaked HTML template?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but I have a similar problem right now. If found a solution, but it's not very elegant. I hope there is something better...
You can wrap your item in $any() operator like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="$any(item).checked" *ngIf="!item.icon">
<i class="{{$any(item).icon}}" *ngIf="item.icon">
```

That should work.

Comment: I didn't know the `$any()`  Useful as a last resort (like `as any` in TypeScript). In my case, it bothers me to have to use it several times. But it gave me the idea of using a function to make the compiler happy - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67516737/8634147 : a little better, still not perfect though 

Comment: Yeah, that's slightly cleaner but still a hack. Maybe someone comes up with a better solution at some point.
From my perspective, that is a very common use case: you want to display a list of items which are not all of the same type, and depening on the type display different things. There should be the possibility to handle this in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not the solution I expected but a tweak*

We can type our `item` with the union type and still use it in the HTML template but via a `tweak` function that just adjusts the type to make the 2 inner types compatible with each other. So, the idea is to use a "tweaked item" in the HTML template and still use a regular item in the rest of the TypeScript code.

Here a demo code in TypeScript where `props` simulates the usage made in the HTML template:

```
type Item =
  | { checked: boolean }
  | { icon: string };

const items: Item[] = [{ checked: true }, { icon: 'checked' }];

const propsKo = items.map(x => ({ checked: x.checked, icon: x.icon }));
//                                           ~~~~~~~          ~~~~
//  Property 'xxx' (icon/checked) does not exist on type 'Item'


//  Tweak
type ItemTweaked =
  | { checked: boolean; icon: never }
  | { icon: string; checked: never };

const tweak = (item: Item) => item as ItemTweaked;

const propsOk = items.map(tweak).map(x => ({ checked: x.checked, icon: x.icon }));
//                        ^^^^^
```